# Cannot debug an xUnit Theory case

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, xunit, .net-5

So I have an xUnit project running on VS 2019. The specs are as follows:

- VS2019 (16.9.3)
- xUnit 2.4.1
- xUnit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.3
- FluentAssertions 5.10.3
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.9.4

I have a simple test case in the xUnit project which looks as follows:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Hello", "World")]
    public void ShouldGreetEntity(string greeting, string entityname)
    {
        var expected = $"{greeting} {entityname}";

        var returned = $"{greeting} {entityname}";

        returned.Should().Be(expected);
    }
```

Ignore the sensibility of the test case.

I have no issues with running the test case. It runs and give me passed result. However, upon trying to debug this test case, it pops up a tab prompting me to locate a 'TestClass.cs' file. It looks as follows:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what this is about?

Comment: What is the name of the file which contains your "ShouldGreetEntity" test?

Comment: I think you're using an old version of Xunit, which is confusing things slightly? Either way, it looks like the debugger's broken inside an Xunit file (perhaps because an exception is thrown at that point?), but it's failed to find the corresponding source file. Check the "Stack Trace" window to confirm/disprove this. The easiest thing to do is to turn **on** "Just My Code", under Debug -> Options. That will stop the debugger breaking in code which isn't yours

Comment: Well!! Latest versions of the xUnit packages are v.2.4.1 and v2.4.3 respectively, so we're good on that front. Will have a look at the stack trace window.

Comment: Aha, the path `src/xunit.execution` hasn't existed since around 2018, but then the last release of xunit was in 2018, so that's fair enough.

Comment: It's definitely trying to break into an xunit type though, so I stand by my suggestion to enable Just My Code (or use the Call Stack window to tell VS to open a type it does actually have the source for, such as your unit test suite)

Comment: So I verified that 'Just My Code' has always been enabled. I also checked the 'Call Stack' window which automatically pops up when I am debugging. That did not show me much. I do not remember creating this TestClass.cs class or file, but searched the entire solution for its existence and found nothing.

Comment: Ok!! I just checked the Breakpoint window which also pops up while debugging. It showed a breakpoint on TestClass.cs. Double-clicking on it did nothing. I stopped the debugger, deleted all breakpoints, cleaned and re-built the project and debugged the test case. It works fine now.

Comment: I mean the [this window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @canton7, after reviewing the 'Call Stack' and 'Breakpoint' windows, I found there was a breakpoint on a non-existent file called 'TestClass.cs'. Deleting all breakpoints fixed this issue.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).